# Is it safe to add a new line charactor (\n) in the sql query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, newline

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        sql.append("SELECT C.ID,\n" +
                "    CODE\n" +
                "  FROM DB.TEATABLE C\n" +
                "  LEFT JOIN\n" +
                "    (SELECT IT.TEA,\n" +
                "      IT.COFFEETYPE,\n" +
                "      XREF.AUSTIN_COFFEE_LEAF_CODE AS LEAFCODE\n" +
                "    FROM DB.COFFEE_AUSTIN_XREF XREF,\n" +
                "      DB.INDIAPLAN TP,\n" +
                "      DB.COFFEE IT,\n" +
                "      DB.TEATABLE C\n" +
                "    WHERE C.ID            = IT.TEA\n" +
                "    AND IT.COFFEETYPE  = 'RIL'\n" +
                "    AND IT.INDIAPLANID   =TP.ID");
con     = getConnection();
pstmt   = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
rs      = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

We used to add new line charactor as above. Is it safe to add `\n` character in the query (in Oracle)?

Comment: Why you would add it? It makes no sence

Comment: @Jens may be for the purpose of formatting while printing query in console or in log file

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh , It's Oracle. I edited the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Jens , I am new to this project. I even dont know why they have added it. It might be the reason what Pragnani said.

Comment: This can be quite easily answered by yourself: does this query fail: it isn't safe; if it doesn't fail, then it is safe.

Comment: @Tom , I dont think that is not a correct answer. Just think I am running it in my developement machine with Oracle 10 and in production there is Oracle 11. I dont know whether this code will break or not. So I hope my question is relevent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to add newlines (`\n` or `\r\n`) to your query. Most parsers consider newlines as whitespace (just like a space or tab), and so does the one used by Oracle (and all other database I have used).

You have already proven this, because based on your comments your company already does this (and probably has so for years). I'm curious as to why you think it could be unsafe. Because obviously it works, and if it would be unsafe, Oracle would disallow it with a clear error.

Although very subjective, it could be better than not doing it, as it allows for a easier visual inspection if all lines end in whitespace. Consider the difference between:

1. Oops, no space

   ```
   "select *" +
   "from table"
   ```
2. Space

   ```
   "select * " +
   "from table"
   ```
3. Linebreak

   ```
   "select *\n" +
   "from table"
   ```

The difference between 1 and 2 is smaller than between 1 and 3. Especially in long queries this might matter to see if you forgot whitespace which might either lead to a syntax error, or worse to incorrect query behavior.

On the other hand, the newlines are extra visual clutter that might distract from reading the query. When in doubt, go with what is the norm or codestyle in your company.

Comment: Thank you Mark. About your doubt "I'm curious as to why you think it could be unsafe." -> I dont know whether this will make any issue running in different versions. Your answer is good to go for me. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

**Yes! But** make sure your newlines are **actually newlines**.

I was trouble shooting for 3 hours thinking it was my sql syntax
because I used:

---

```
String N = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
```

---

I thought I had a newline character,
but I was actually inserting **nulls** into my statement.

Error Messages Included:

1:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "NULLnull"
> ```

2:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
> ERROR: conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations 
>        for column "nullid" of table "t_1"
> ```

3:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "KEYnull"
> ```

4:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "null"
> ```

I thought I was my primary key statement:

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

For longer than I would like to admit.